# Managing Two .env Files (Development and Production) in a React Project

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, dotenv, react-scripts

If I create two `.env` files, one named `.env.development` and the other `.env.production`, in the main directory and I add the following scripts to my `package.json`:

```
    "start": "NODE_ENV=development react-scripts start",
    "build": "NODE_ENV=production react-scripts build"
```

what happens when I run `npm start` and `npm run build`?

For `npm start`, I understand it will use `.env.development`, but for `npm run build`, will it exclusively use `.env.production` in the production environment? Or will it include all `.env` files from the main directory in the build?

Additionally, is it safe to store API keys in `.env.development` or should I avoid doing that?

Comment: *is it safe to store API keys in .env.development or should I avoid doing that?* - There is no way to hide keys in a client-side application

Comment: @Konrad I know. I don't want to use the keys in the build. I already have a back-end proxy server for it. I'm asking for development on my local with keys. But I want to be sure that `.env.development` won't be in the build when I run `npm run build` with this setup.

Comment: FWIW I think this is a mug's game (and `dotenv` itself [discourages it](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv#should-i-have-multiple-env-files)) Use a single `.env` (`.gitignore`'d, local only) for development purposes. When you _build_, don't do that locally at all - deploy automatically and repeatably from a pipeline of some kind, and inject _actual env vars_ at that point. Even better, use deploy- or run-time configuration, so you can have a single artefact rather than needing to rebuild for each environment (more [here](https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2020/Sep/19/spa-config.html)).

Comment: @Konrad Actually I tried to find `.env` variables in the build. I even don't have two `.env` files right now or a specific setup on package.json, but still, I couldn't find `.env` variable when I edit JS file with Notepad++. I searched with Ctrl+F. So the problem is I don't know how can I find `.env` files in builds even though I know they are always embedded in builds.

Comment: These variables are replaced with their content in the build files

Comment: @Konrad Yes I searched with their contents, not their names. I added `REACT_APP_TEST='This is test'` to `.env`. Then in one of the components, I declare `const test=process.env.REACT_APP_TEST`, then in the build, I searched for '`This is test`' but I couldn't find it. Then I give it to a `useCase` variable as an initialize value like `useCase(test)`, still couldn't find in the build. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to manually set `NODE_ENV` in your `package.json` scripts, as Webpack automatically manages it. In production, it `exclusively` uses `.env.production`, and the content of `.env.development` won't be included in the `build` folder. If the content of `.env.development` is sensitive, ensure not to push it to `Git`, and maintain it on your local machine for security.

Add `.env.development` to .gitignore as follows:

```
.env.development
/coverage
build
npm-debug.log*
yarn-debug.log*
yarn-error.log*
```

Keep in mind that if you haven't used customized env variables in your code, they won't appear in the build files.

Comment: Thank you for a detailed explanation. You said, "_if you haven't used customized env variables in your code, they won't appear in the build files_". I added `REACT_APP_TEST='This is test'` to `.env`. Then in one of the components, I declare `const test=process.env.REACT_APP_TEST`, then in the build, I searched for '`This is test`' in Notepad++ but I couldn't find it. Then I give it to a `useCase` variable as an initialize value like `useCase(test)`, still couldn't find in the build. What am I missing?

Comment: Your const is declared, but its value is never used. If you place this variable inside a JSX element and render it, it will then appear in the build folder.

Comment: Keep in mind that Webpack intelligently removes all unused variables or functions during the build process.

Comment: So you are saying that, only if it is placed in a JSX element, it will appear in the build? But what about API keys? We never use them in a JSX element, only for fetching data from API, but as I searched, it's still not safe and can be found in the build somehow. Isn't it true?

Comment: No, if the API functions are called, the Key values are placed in the 'build' folder.

Comment: Ok, I understand, I will try. Thank you very much.